# How to merge Foo<A> | Foo<B> into Foo<A | B>

Tags: typescript

I fell into a case where I have the following variable :

```
var foo: Foo<string> | Foo<number> | Foo<boolean>;
```

generated dynamically (using keyof and stuff), which is fully intended at that point of the code. But then, I need to call methods inside that object defined like this :

```
class Foo<T> {
    pipe(): Foo<T>;
    pipe<A, B>(obj: Operator<T, A>, obj2: Operator<A, B>): Foo<B>;
    pipe<A>(obj: Operator<T, A>): Foo<A>;
    pipe(...obj: Operator[]): Foo<any> {
        return new Foo();
    }
}
```

The problem being, when I do the following :

```
const f = foo.pipe((bar) => new Foo());
```

`bar` is infered as `string` while I'd expect `string | number | boolean`.

My guess here is that I need to convert `Foo<string> | Foo<number> | Foo<boolean>` into `Foo<string | number | boolean>` where it solves the problem.

How can I do such convertion ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a conditional type to achieve this (union types distribute over unions which helps us in this case)

```
type UnionOfFooToFooOfUnion<T extends Foo<any> > = Foo< T extends Foo<infer U> ? U : never>

let foo!: Foo<string> | Foo<number> | Foo<boolean>;

let merged: UnionOfFooToFooOfUnion<typeof foo> =  foo // we can just assign it
```

Or we could use a function:

```
function mergeFoo<T extends Foo<any>>(foo: T): UnionOfFooToFooOfUnion<T> {
    return foo;
}
mergeFoo(foo).pipe(s=> console.log(s)) // s is number | string | boolean
```

Comment: @RémiRousselet improved it with a function version as well

Comment: Do you know if there's any way to remove `Foo` from the typedef/function ?

Comment: @RémiRousselet I though about it but I don't know of a solution